# What is the formula for loan payoff with daily compounded interest and annual payment?

Tags: loans, payment, compound-interest, amortization, principal

I am trying to get the loan repayment amount for below data :

Loan Amount: $20,412.65
Payments (#): 10
Annual Interest Rate: 2.5%
Loan Date: 07/02/2018
First Payment Due: 09/02/2018 (next payment will be on 09/02/2019 then 09/02/2020 and so on)
Payment Frequency:  Annually
Compounding: Daily

My Bank is charging me $2,285.18 for each repayment amount for 10 installments.

Can you please help with the formula on how bank is calculating it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula derived here: [Calculating interest accrued with extended Initial Payment Date](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/63197/11768)

First period extension is negative: `x = -10/12` reducing the first period to 2 months.

```
pv = 20412.65
r = 2.5/100
n = 10

pv = (c (1 + r)^(-n - x) (-1 + (1 + r)^n))/r

∴ c = (pv r (1 + r)^(n + x))/(-1 + (1 + r)^n)

∴ c = 2284.82
```

Which is pretty close to $2,285.18

Reducing the granularity to days ...

62 days between 07/02/2018 and 09/02/2018

```
x = -(360 - 62)/360

∴ c = 2285.14
```

360 day year gets closer to the repayment amount than 365.

The bank’s calculation may differ slightly, but this is the general idea.

***Alternative method***

Calculate interest to first payment, add to principal.  Calculate payment for an [annuity due](http://financeformulas.net/Annuity-Due-Payment-from-Present-Value.html).

```
s = pv (1 + r)^(62/360) = 20499.64

c = s (r/(1 - (1 + r)^-n))*1/(1 + r) = 2285.14
```