# Calculating Amortization Payment Amount when first payment is early

Tags: compound-interest, amortization

How can I determine a fixed payment amount for a loan that has an early first payment?

Example:

```
Loan Amount: $100  
Interest: 10%  
Loan Date: January 1st, 2018
First Payment Date: January 15th, 2018 
Term: 10 Years, payments made yearly on January 15th
```

Normally I'd use the Amortization Payment Formula below, but in this case it doesn't seem to work.  My guess is that *P* needs to be adjusted to be somewhat less, but it's not clear how to calculate that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/97158/11768),

Calculate the interest accrued in 14 days, add it to the principal giving `s`.  Then calculate the regular payment for an [annuity due](http://financeformulas.net/Annuity-Due-Payment-from-Present-Value.html).

```
p = 100
r = 0.10
n = 10

s = p (1 + r)^(14/365) = 100.366
a = s (r/(1 - (1 + r)^-n))*1/(1 + r) = 14.8492
```

The regular payment is $14.85

For more information on the difference between an ordinary annuity and an annuity due see [Present and Future Value of Annuities](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities/).

Comment: Didn't know about the annuity due formula.  Thanks!

Comment: @BradThiessen No probs.