# Calculating mortgage schedule

Tags: mortgage, home-loan, poland

I am trying to figure out formulas used in my friend's history of payments unfortunately I can't figure out how bank calculates some of them.

**All values in tables represent real payments history of that loan** I am trying to find formulas to calculate them

Variables:

- Loan Amount : 160000 PLN (Polish Złoty)
- Interest rate : 2,37%
- Loan Term : 120 months
- Payment is made each month on 15th or next working day.
- Reference rate is updated every 6 months.
- Year has always 365 days
- Banks started charging interests from 2nd of October 2020
- First payment 16th of November 2020 (because 15/11/2020 was sunday)

Knowing this stuff I was able to calculate monthly payment using PMT formula in excel

```
 PMT(Interest Rate/ 12;120;Loan Amount) =  1498,88
```

| Payment date | Rate | Payment | Interests | Principal | Balance | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/11/2020 | 0,0237 | 1498,88 | 471,51 | 1031,37 | 158968,63 | 15/11/2020 is Sunday |

To calculate Interest part I came up with this formula :

```
d = Days difference between 2/10/2020 and 16/11/2020 -> 45
Loan Amount * Interest Rate * (d /365) = 471.51
```

Next payments

| Payment date | Rate | Payment | Interest | Principal | Balance | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/12/2020 | 0,0237 | 1498,88 | 309,66 | 1189,22 | 157779,41 | 30 days |
| 15/01/2021 | 0,0237 | 1498,88 | 317,59 | 1181,29 | 156598,12 | 31 days |

Here is another thing that I don't know how to calculate.

- 02/10/2020 to 16/11/2020 => 45 days
- 16/11/2020 to 15/12/2020 => 29 days but I need 30 to get correct
  interest
- 15/12/2020 to 15/01/2021 => 30 days but I need 31 to get correct
  interest

Maybe I would be able to finally figure how data difference is calculate with more data, but there is another problem I am unable to solve.

At `21.01.2021` the interest rate drop by 0.05%, because bank became owner of the property and because of that they drop the rate.

| Payment date | Rate | Payment | Interest | Principal | Balance | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/02/2021 | 0,0232 | 1496,81 | 309,85 | 1186,96 | 155411,16 |  |

I have no idea how `1496,81` and `309,85` were calculated. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the charge for the extended first period by the method used [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/63238/11768)

```
principal      p = 160000
monthly rate   r = 0.0237/12
no. months     n = 120
```

2nd Oct to 15th Oct 2020 is 13 days

```
one month's interest  m1 = r p = 316

13 day's interest    d13 = (p + m1)*(0.0237/365)*13 = 135.32

1st interest charge (Nov)   c1 = m1 + d13 = 451.32
```

Reset principal to `s` and calculate payment amount `d` for an [annuity due](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities/) so that the November repayment is applied straight away.

```
s = p + c1 = 160451.32

d = (r (1 + r)^(n - 1) s)/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 1500.14
```

This does not match the OP's payment amount because the OP's figure does not include an extended first period.  I.e. calculating an ordinary annuity payment

```
d = (r (1 + r)^n p)/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 1498.88
```

***Matching the bank's figures***

1496.81 and 309.85 can be obtained thus

```
p = 156598.12   (January balance)
r = 0.0232/12
n = 117
```

With an ordinary annuity formula

```
d = (r (1 + r)^n p)/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 1496.81
```

The February interest charge

```
p (6*0.0237 + 25*0.0232)/365 = 309.85
```

Comment: At first I came up with exactly same values, but they are not what bank actually charged. All values in tables represent a real payments history of that loan.

Comment: Closest I can get to the first interest payment is `160000*0.0237 (15/365 + 1/12) = 471.84`